Do we have a verb to express "you give a seat to an old person on a train when no seat is available"?
On a crowded train, there is no available seat. An old man gets on the train looking around for a seat. You stand up and give your seat to him.
Do we have a specific verb to express "you give a seat to an old person on a train when no seat is available"?

No special word, but "yield your seat" or "concede your seat" would be slightly more formal alternatives to "give (up) your seat", or with a slight change in tone, "offer (someone) your seat"
The seats designated as such are called "priority seats"
The tradition of who gets to sit in a priority seat varies from culture to culture. In some cultures it is mostly for the elderly, in others it is for children, disabled people, pregnant women, or people with young children. In some cultures it is just "those in need".

Or "offer him your seat" (which might be an ordinary seat and not a priority one!).

yield or concede a seat? Sounds like a by-election...

Yes, you'd never say "dear daughter, please yield your seat to the old man"  but a bus by-law might say "Passengers seated in the priority area must yield to those in need".

Relinquish
Part with a possession or right
"I am relinquishing my seat reservation to the pregnant woman"
